# Assembly: Convert hex string into single byte

Tags: assembly, hex

In assembly, say you have a hex string of '0x2f'. How would you convert this into a single byte of the value '0x2f'?

Example (Assumes SI equals the location of your 2-character hex string, and conv_hex2byte does the conversion, returning the result in AL):

```
jmp    main
foo    db '2f'
bar    db 0
main:
    mov    si, foo
    call    conv_hex2byte
    mov    byte [bar], al
    ; bar should now have a value of '2f'
    ret
conv_hex2byte:
    ; What would go here?
    ret
```

Edit: I've got this attempt at conv_hex2byte...

```
conv_hex2byte:
push    ebx
push    ecx
push    edx

; Clear general registers
xor eax, eax
mov bx, .tmp0
mov ecx, eax
mov edx, eax

.char:
lodsb
mov dl, al
cmp dl, '0'
jl  .is_hex
cmp dl, '9'
jg  .is_hex
sub al, '0' ; Make '0' = 0h
.write_val:
mov bx, .tmp0
add bx, cx
mov [bx], dl
inc cl
cmp cl, 2
jl  .char
mov ah, byte [.tmp0]
shl ah, 4
mov al, byte [.tmp1]
or  al, ah
xor ah, ah
;call   os_dump_registers
pop edx
pop ecx
pop ebx
ret

.is_hex:
cmp dl, 'F'
jg  .lower
sub dl, 55 ; Make 'A' = 0ah
jmp .write_val

.lower:
sub dl, 87 ; Make 'a' = 0ah
jmp .write_val

.tmp0   db 0
.tmp1   db 0
```

For some reason, it produces the wrong number... i.e.

```
push hex
call conv_hex2byte
hex db '20'
```

results in AX equaling `0x32` rather than `0x20`.

Comment: When you have at least *tried* to solve the problem, come back if you still need help.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have tried, and failed many times. My guess is that I'm misunderstanding the correct process of doing so.

Comment: Then show your best attempt, and maybe someone can help fix it.

Comment: @ScottHunter I added my best attempt, but it is still erroneous.